# Read File Contents Into Memory At Java Compile

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

This is probably a basic question that has some sort of solution that I am not aware of, but basically I have a apache-tomcat web application that hosts a lot of different sites and each visitor needs access to the contents of an xml file. There are about 6 different xml files that this could be. If I allow the file to be accessed each time (the file is used in lots of included pages and assets) I get too many files open, if I store it in the sessions, I get too much memory usage.

What I would like is when I compile the classes to have one class read each of the files into memory and then to access that data like a constant. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe consider closing the file. Or caching the contents, but this seems unnecessary.

Comment: Why not store the files in the `ServletContext` at startup of the application?

Comment: Or in other words store it in the application context, not the session context.

Comment: @Dave I was closing the file. The problem is just that it happens too fast, there's over 3000 websites with a lot of files that need the information from this file.

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic case where a singleton would be useful. A singleton is often used to load content only once.

A modified example from the wikipedia page on Singletons (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    private String xmlFileContents;

    private Singleton() {
        // Call method to populate xmlFileContents field from XML file
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getXMLFileContents() {
        return xmlFileContents;
    }
}
```